# Preparation steps for sending a phone back under warranty

Tags: privacy

I'm sending my (unrooted) nexus s off repair under under warranty, and was just wondering if there any precautions I can take to limit the amount of personal info on the device, lest the engineers take a look through my contacts/emails etc.? (ideally without resetting phone to factory defaults)

Main ideas I've had so far are:

- Associating the phone with a brand new google account and deleting the old ones
- Moving all sd card content to computer
- Clearing caches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resetting the phone to factory settings (`Menu -> Settings -> Privacy -> Factory data reset`) and wiping the microSD card (after backing up its contents) should be all that's needed.

Factory reset dis-associates the phone from your Google account, removes any custom apps (installed on internal memory) with their data, and clears all the caches.

*[Edit]*
P.S. There is a good chance that the manufacturer (Samsung in your case) or whoever you are sending your phone to for repairs might send you a different handset.  Depending on their service terms, they may simply ship you a brand new Nexus S, or even a refurb.  So jumping through hoops to leave your installed apps intact might be a waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it looks like you want to clear everything except your apps.  Is that right?  If so, I'd just use something like [App Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=de.android_telefonie.appmanager) to back them all up, and then do a factory reset.  If you back them up to the SD card they should be safe, but you can always copy the backup to your computer.